# Custom sort order function for groupby pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a grouped dataframe like the below (which was obtained through an initial `df.groupby(df["A"]).apply(some_func)` where `some_func` returns a dataframe itself). The second column is the second level of the `multiindex` which was created by the `groupby`.

```
A   B C
1 0 1 8
  1 3 3
2 0 1 2
  1 2 2
3 0 1 3
  1 2 4
```

And I would like to order on the result of a custom function that I apply to the groups.

Let's assume for this example that the function is

```
def my_func(group):
    return sum(group["B"]*group["C"])
```

I would then like the result of the sort operation to return

```
A   B C
2 0 1 2
  1 2 2
3 0 1 3
  1 2 4
1 0 1 8
  1 3 3
```

Comment: What is a "grouped dataframe"? I only see a dataframe there with blanks in the first column. Could you please clarify what these groups are and how the function is applied to them? Some additional context would be very helpful.

Comment: edited the question to clarify that my dataframe is the result of a `groupby.apply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on @Wen-Ben's excellent answer, but uses `sort_values` to maintain the intra/inter group orders.

```
df['func'] = (groups.apply(my_func)
              .reindex(df.index.get_level_values(0))
              .values)

(df.reset_index()
 .sort_values(['func','A','i'])
 .drop('func', axis=1)
 .set_index(['A','i']))
```

**Note**: the default algorithm for `idx.argsort()`, `quicksort`, is not stable. That's why @Wen-Ben's answer fails for complicated datasets. You can use `idx.argsort(kind='mergesort')` for a stable sort, i.e., maintaining the original order in case of tie values.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `reindex` after `apply` your function then ,do with `argsort`

```
idx=df.groupby('A').apply(my_func).reindex(df.index.get_level_values(0))
df.iloc[idx.argsort()]
Out[268]: 
     B  C
A       
2 0  1  2
  1  2  2
3 0  1  3
  1  2  4
1 0  1  8
  1  3  3
```

Comment: very nice thank you. Although it does change the intra-group order which I would like to keep. Any way to modify what you offered to suit that query ?

Comment: also on my more involved real data, the groups are not even kept together : could it be because `my_func` gives the exact same value for different values of "A" ?

Comment: yes it was. so only left with keeping the original intra-group order (the second level of the original multiindex created by the first groupby)