# keep second level of multi-index intact while sorting on first one pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have sorted my first level of index using the following method : [Custom sort order function for groupby pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033073/custom-sort-order-function-for-groupby-pandas-python)

```
def my_func(group):
    return sum(group["B"]*group["C"])

idx=df.groupby('A').apply(my_func).reindex(df.index.get_level_values(0))
df.iloc[idx.argsort()]
```

The issue is that the second level ordering is jumbled up after sorting on the first. How can I make sure that the intra-group order is kept ?

from

```
A   B C
1 0 1 8
  1 3 3
2 0 1 2
  1 2 2
3 0 1 3
  1 2 4
```

to

```
A   B C
2 0 1 2
  1 2 2
3 0 1 3
  1 2 4
1 0 1 8
  1 3 3
```

and not (last 2 lines inverted)

```
A   B C
2 0 1 2
  1 2 2
3 0 1 3
  1 2 4
1 1 3 3
  0 1 8
```

Comment: how did you sort it? I can't see the sort hahaha

Comment: added the function in the question but it won't produce the result I gave. The jumbling of intra-group rows happen in my more involved data, not the example one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need stable sorting [algo](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) - `mergesort`:

```
idx=df.index.get_level_values(0).map(df.groupby('A').apply(my_func))
df = df.iloc[idx.argsort(kind='mergesort')]
print (df)
     B  C
A        
2 0  1  2
  1  2  2
3 0  1  3
  1  2  4
1 0  1  8
  1  3  3
```

Comment: Thank you ! was bugging me for a few hours now !

Comment: @Chapo - You are not first, I once have same problem and really long time was found solution. Btw, in pandas is same problem if use sorting by one column, then default is also `quicksort`. But is sortng by multiple columns default is `mergesort`